# My nav ul li is displayed vertically at first loading instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css

On the top of my page I have a navigation with some items ligned horizontally. When I first go on the page it is not horzontally, instead its vertically arragend. What ever when I reload the page it is normal again.

**This is my navigation:**

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="menu"> <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <ul>
        <a href="#home">
            <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#services">
            <li>Services</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#work">
            <li>Work</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#contact">
            <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
header nav ul li {
    margin-left: 25px;
    float: left;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

**I already tried:**

```
header nav ul li {
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

...which works fine, but when I hover then all items are going down instead of just the one I hovered.

**Its hard to explain my issue but you might get the same when visiting the page:**

[my page](http://www.leet-programming.com/) I use google chrome browser.

When you've got further question just ask

Thank you

Comment: your code is invalid: the children of a list are list-items, not links

Comment: use li tag in ul tag for each element -  The <li> tag is written as <li></li> with the list item inserted between the start and end tags. The element must be placed inside either a <ol> tag or a <ul> tag to provide each individual list item within those elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this HTML code once..

```
<nav id="menu">
                <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning what you changed (making the `<li>` tag the direct child of the `<ul>` tag) and why that's important

Comment: this is important because this is the simple formation of list. if u don't follow this formation it can break in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. It will help you.

```css
header nav ul li {
  margin-left: 25px;
  float: left;
}

header nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <ul>
        <a href="#home">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#services">
          <li>Services</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#work">
          <li>Work</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#contact">
          <li>Contact</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine, I also put the a tag inside the li tag, as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Please try using anchor-tags inside the list(li) tags.